# 422 status code when sending valid data, API with Flask, SQLAlchemy

Tags: python-3.x, flask, sqlalchemy, http-status-code-422

I am building Library API project, and my code used to work just fine, but recently - when I aimed to finish working with it - I was checking my endpoints, and this is what I get when sending POST request:

```
{
    "book_id":1,
    "client_id":2,
    "date_rented":"2023-07-06"
}
# ----------------------------------
{
    "code": 422,
    "errors": {
        "json": {
            "book_id": [
                "Missing data for required field."
            ],
            "client_id": [
                "Missing data for required field."
            ],
            "date_rented": [
                "Missing data for required field."
            ]
        }
    },
    "status": "Unprocessable Entity"
}
```

I checked everything from endpoint through Model and Schema, but everything seems to be fine. Below I sent the rest of related code.

endpoint:

```
@blp.route('/rental')
class ListBookRental(MethodView):
 @blp.arguments(PlainRentSchema)
    @blp.response(201, PlainRentSchema)
    def post(self, rent_data):

        book = BookModel.query.get_or_404(rent_data['book_id'])
        book_rent = BookRentModel(**rent_data)

        if book.status != "available":
            abort(500, "You can not rent this book!")
        else:
            book.status = "rented"
            book.times_rented += 1
        try:
            db.session.add(book_rent)
            db.session.commit()
        except SQLAlchemyError:
            abort(500, "SQLAlchemyError occurred while inserting rent.")

        return jsonify({"message": "Rent created."}), 201
```

model:

```
class BookRentModel(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "book_rent"

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    book_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("books.id"), unique=False, nullable=False)
    client_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("clients.id"), unique=False, nullable=False)
    date_rented = db.Column(db.Date, unique=False, nullable=False)
    date_returned = db.Column(db.Date, unique=False, nullable=True)
   
    books = db.relationship("BookModel", back_populates="book_rents")
    client = db.relationship("ClientModel", back_populates="book_rent")
```

schema:

```
class PlainRentSchema(Schema):
    id = fields.Integer(dump_only=True)
    book_id = fields.Integer(required=True)
    client_id = fields.Integer(required=True)
    date_rented = fields.Date(required=True)
    date_returned = fields.Date(required=False)

    books = fields.Nested(PlainBookSchema(), dump_only=True)
```

I checked the spelling, re-wrote request and nothing. I did research this, but all I could find was explanation of 422 status code. I compared this code to the rest of my project POST methods, and they're working fine. Maybe I don't see the obvious?
Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: i work with Insomnia